# Swift enum pattern matching with associated values - cannot invoke function

Tags: ios, swift, enums, pattern-matching

I get an error I cannot explain when trying to call the `count()` function in a switch case with enums:

```
enum Token{

    case Name(String)

    var count:Int{ 
        switch self{
        case .Name(let string):
            return count(string)
        }
    }
}
```

The error is `Cannot invoke 'count' with an argument list of type '((String))'`.

I also tried

```
case .Name(let string):
      return string.characters.count
```

with the error `'String' does not have a member named 'characters'`.

Anybody an idea what I`m doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift thinks you are trying to access the `count` property instead of calling the global `count` function.  You can fix this by calling `Swift.count(string)`:

**Swift 1.2:**

```
enum Token{

    case Name(String)

    var count:Int{
        switch self{
        case .Name(let string):
            return Swift.count(string)
        }
    }
}
```

For **Swift 2:**

The second syntax you tried is actually correct for Swift 2:

```
        case .Name(let string):
            return string.characters.count
```